# Select all text in a word, except first letter

Tags: regex, awk

Hi like to change all text in a word, except first letter.

```
cat file
TEST
BEST
```

Then I thought I could do:

```
awk '{sub(/[^.].*/,"X",$1)}1' file
X
X
```

This is my expected output:

```
TX
BX
```

---

This is OK

```
awk '{sub(/[^B].*/,"X",$1)}1' file
X
BX
```

---

This is OK too

```
awk '{sub(/[^BT].*/,"X",$1)}1' file
TX
BX
```

---

But this is not OK

```
awk '{sub(/[^A-Z].*/,"X",$1)}1' file
TEST
BEST
```

```
awk '{sub(/[^a-z].*/,"X",$1)}1' file
X
X
```

I know this has some with my character set.

---

Then I tested this, not working

```
awk '{sub(/[^[:alpha:]].*/,"X",$1)}1' file
TEST
BEST
```

---

And with anchor.

```
awk '{sub(/^[^.].*$/,"X",$1)}1'
X
X
```

Any idea on how to get this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use captured group to capture the first letter and then replace everything. This is possible using `gensub` (available in GNU `awk` ver. 3.2 or later).

```
$ cat file
TEST
BEST
$ awk '{print gensub(/(.).*/,"\\1X","g",$0)}' file
TX
BX
```

#### Why does your following solution doesn't work:

```
awk '{sub(/[^[:alpha:]].*/,"X",$1)}1' file
```

Well, it is pretty straightforward. Your RE is telling `awk` to select anything that doesn't contain a string that starts with an `[:alpha:]` character class, since your data doesn't have that, nothing gets selected and your file is printed out as is.

If you modify your file to be:

```
$ cat file
TEST
BEST
%HELLO
```

```
$ awk '{sub(/[^[:alpha:]].*/,"X",$1)}1' file
TEST
BEST
X
```

#### `awk` solution:

One way to do it with `awk` would be to add a unique character to first letter and use `gsub` to remove the rest (consider work around method).

```
$ awk '{sub(/./,"&\n",$1);gsub(/\n.*/,"X",$1)}1' file
TX
BX
```

You can use `SUBSEP` as a unique character to differentiate between two pieces. `SUBSEP` is an `awk` built-in variable that contains a non-printing character which gives you some leverage to not accidentally select something from the data itself.

```
$ awk '{sub(/./,"&SUBSEP",$1);gsub(/SUBSEP.*/,"X",$1)}1' file
TX
BX
```

Comment: An ok solution, but like to see it with generic `awk` and why my does not work :)

Comment: @Jotne Added a note why your solution didn't work and added an awk solution (work-around). The unique character can also be `SUBSEP` which is a non-printing character, used by `awk` too for simulating multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/../{print substr($1,1,1)"X"}' file
TX
BX
```

#### Other approaches

```
awk '{sub(/[^A-Z].*/,"X",$1)}1' file
TEST
BEST
```

The above doesn't work because the regex never matches: the strings have only capital letters.

```
awk '{sub(/[^a-z].*/,"X",$1)}1' file
X
X
```

The above replaces the whole string because it matches the whole string.

```
awk '{sub(/[^[:alpha:]].*/,"X",$1)}1' file
TEST
BEST
```

Because all characters in your file are alpha, the above regex never matches.

As far as I know, awk's `sub` lacks advanced regex facilities like grouping or look-back that would allow it to work here.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this in non-GNU awk is:

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,1,1) "X"}' file
TX
BX
```

or using an RE if you have a need for it:

```
awk 'match($0,/.[[:alpha:]]+/){ $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART) "X" substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) } 1' file
```

In general anything you need gensub() for in gawk, you can accomplish in non-GNU awks using match()+substr() (sometimes in a loop).

If you have some input that that doesn't work for, please update your question to include that input along with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sth. like the following:

```
awk '{sub(/EST/,"X")}1' file
TX
BX
```